# Eclipse product is not detecting dropins plugins and not updating bundles.info

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment, p2-director

I have migrated my eclipse RCP product from eclipse 3.8 to eclipse 4.12. Whenever we add any additional plugin to plugins or dropins folder. It was reflected in bundles.info in eclipse 3.8. But in eclipse 4.12 it is not updating bundles.info file and it is causing errors while launching.

Why it is not updating bundles.info?

Directory:

> \eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info

Folder Structure

- eclipse

  - plugins
  - dropins
  - configuration

Comment: Have you included the p2 plugins? Have you included `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins` and `org.apache.felix.scr` in the start levels?

Comment: Yes, I have included the p2 plugins. 

`<plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />`
 and  
`<plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" /> `

Comment: Eclipse itself has the start level for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins as 4, possibly 1 is to soon.

Comment: It is not updating the **bundles.info** even after using p2 plugins.